# Can we extrapolate wind speed data to higher altitudes?

Tags: meteorology, wind, air-currents

I have some data (GRIB layers) about wind components u and v, which I would like to use to estimate wind magnitude and direction. But the model says it is for 10 m altitude.

Is there a way to extrapolate this value for higher altitudes? lets say 600 m. If yes, how? which other variables should I consider that can bias this calculation?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but it may not be valid. The extrapolation will be valid for about 0.1 * [PBL](http://elte.prompt.hu/sites/default/files/tananyagok/AtmosphericChemistry/ch01s05.html) Height using the [Log-Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_wind_profile) Profile

You will need:

- PBL Height.
- A second Wind speed (within 0.1*PBL Height)
- Surface Sensible Heat Flux
- Surface Latent Heat Flux
- [Potential Temperature](https://www.shodor.org/os411/courses/_master/tools/calculators/pottemp/pt1calc.html)

You can use the last three variables to calculate the [Monin-Obukhov Length (MOL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monin%E2%80%93Obukhov_length). Then use the MOL to calculate $\psi$:

If L>0 $\psi=\frac{z}{L}$

If L=0 $\psi=0$

If L<0 $\psi=2\ln(\frac{1+x}{2})+\ln(\frac{1+x^2}{2})-2\tan^{-1}(x)+\frac{\pi}{2}$

where $x=(1-15\frac{z}{L})^{\frac{1}{4}}$

Now that you have $\psi$, you can derive the friction velocity and surface roughness length using the log-wind profile  and $\psi(\frac{z}{L})$. Once you have those two, you can extrapolate wind speed 600 meters up, provided the surface layer is that high.